# How to organize synchronous and asynchronous similar code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, synchronous

I wrote two functions doing the exact same thing, except the first take a synchronous callback, the second an asynchronous one:

```js
const mySyncFn = function(callback) {
  // A: prepare context
  callback();  // execute the callback using context
  // B: cleanup
};

const myAsyncFn = async function(callback) {
  // exactly same code as A
  await callback();
  // exactly same code as B
};
```

How can I organize my code better than duplicating it around the callback call?

Comment: Could you just go for always-async?

Comment: It's hard to answer without concrete code, but you could always put `A` and `B` in helper functions.

Comment: @Bergi I can't always go sync or async. I can put A and B in helpers, but I would like to know if there is any other best practice.

Comment: Your code and intentions are pretty unclear, so I don't know if you know this already, but `mySyncFn` and `myAsyncFn` won't have the same behavior. The former will call `B: cleanup` prior to `callback` completing.

Comment: @junvar, there is an `await` so it actually waits for `callback` before `cleanup` in the `async` version as well.